# SSH - How to add host to ssh/known_host file

Tags: ssh, git, known-hosts

The known_hosts file looks like this :-

```
[localhost]:8001 ssh-dss AAAAB3NzaC1kc3MAAACBAP1/U4EddRIpU   
[10.18.60.198]:8001 ssh-dss AAAAB3NzaC1kc3MAAACBAP1/U4EddRIpUt9
// key are trimmed at the end
```

This keys are added via Eclipse IDE, Want to know what are other ways to add hosts (IPs) and their keys to ssh/known_hosts file.

Specific:- How to add **ssh-dss** key for any host(IP) in known_hosts file.

**EDIT:-**

I am using JBoss BRMS which uses git for BRMS Projects, So at time of cloning the BRMS Project in Eclipse IDE via Git it gives following error

> The authenticity of host 'localhost' can't be established.
>   DSA key fingerprint is e2:2c:62 //trimmed.
>   Are you sure you want to continue connecting?

And it then automatically add ssh-dss key to known_hosts file.

So where to find that key and add it manually on knownhosts file

Comment: Did you just post your private keys on the internet?

Comment: @HackSlash It is not private key and It is trimmed as you can see

Comment: Similar question with complete answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34906302/add-public-key-to-known-hosts-file/34908270#34908270 Safest is to get key out-of-band, generate the line and rehash.

Answer (score 10):

The format of `~/.ssh/known_hosts` is defined by OpenSSH. Other software might either call OpenSSH (the *ssh* command), or might have its own implementations that aren't necessarily 100% compatible.

The OpenSSH known_hosts format is described in the [sshd(8) manual page](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd#SSH_KNOWN_HOSTS_FILE_FORMAT), under "ssh_known_hosts file format". It says that it's a text file with one line per host–key pair:

> Each line in these files contains the following fields: markers (optional), hostnames, keytype, base64-encoded key, comment.  The fields are separated by spaces. […] Hostnames is a comma-separated list of patterns (‘`*`’ and ‘`?`’ act as wildcards); each pattern in turn is matched against the host name. […]  A hostname or address may optionally be enclosed within ‘`[`’ and ‘`]`’ brackets then followed by ‘`:`’ and a non-standard port number.

To automatically add a key for a new host, just SSH to it.

To manually add a key for a new host, 1) open the known_hosts file in your text editor and 2) add the key for a new host, following the same format. (The key must match the host you're connecting to. You can query a host for its key using `ssh-keyscan -t <type> <address>`.)

To add a key for *all* hosts, use a `*` pattern as the hostname, which will match all hostnames and addresses. To add a key for all hosts *on a specific port*, use `[*]:8001` as the hostname.

Comment: How to generate ssh-dss key for any host

Comment: You don't generate it, you copy the key that the host already uses. There is no magic "any host" key.

Comment: i am using jboss EAP, a simple web application server which is running on localhost, where to find ssh-dss key ?

Comment: If your app is running on localhost, then the SSH host itself is localhost. Use your own computer's key then, e.g. from `ssh-keyscan -t dsa localhost`.

Comment: i run this command on git bash on my computer Desktop. but it nothing is displaying on command line.

Comment: @Tarun, did you try just `ssh-keyscan localhost` (without `-t dsa localhost`)?

Comment: @Sasha yes , i run it on git bash but cant find the ssh-dss key of localhost

Comment: @Tarun, sorry for a stupid question, but why do you need specifically a DSS key? What other kinds of keys does `ssh-keyscan localhost` show? Aren't these kinds of keys enough?

Comment: BTW, if the local server of question is running on the port 8001, then you probably need `ssh-keyscan -p 8001 localhost` (instead of `ssh-keyscan localhost`).

Comment: @grawity please see the EDIT in OP

Answer (score 2):

For example you need to add **127.0.0.1** to known_hosts:

```
ssh-keyscan -H 127.0.0.1 >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

For Docker file i use:

```
RUN apt-get update  \
    && apt-get install -y \
    ssh \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && mkdir -p ~/.ssh/ \
    && ssh-keyscan -H 192.168.12.31 >> ~/.ssh/known_hosts
```

Where `apt-get install -y ssh` - make possible use **ssh-keyscan** in command-line, then `rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*` - cleanup downloaded package information with apt.

Answer (score 1):

Try sshing into your target, and then type yes when it asks to save the key.